# Drawing using Forest package

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to place a diagram like below in a beamer. Can anyone please guide me on how this can be done? I am just getting to know about this nice package. Thank You.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={draw,
    rounded corners,
    blur shadow,
    font=\sffamily,
    align=center,
    inner xsep=1em,
    where level=1{fill=green}{fill=green!30},
    s sep+=7em,
    l sep=1em,
    edge={thick,-stealth,shorten <=-1pt},
    }
[Drawing\\ diagrams,
 [Defining node\\ and arrow styles]
 [Drawing arrows\\ between nodes]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={draw,
    rounded corners,
    blur shadow,
    font=\sffamily,
    align=center,
    inner xsep=1em,
    where level=1{fill=green}{fill=green!30},
    s sep+=7em,
    l sep+=1em,
    edge={thick,-stealth},
    }
[Drawing\\ diagrams,
 [Defining node\\ and arrow styles]
 [Drawing arrows\\ between nodes]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]